# Count the occurrences of a given list of values in a column using a single SQL query

Tags: sql, pivot

I would like to get the count of occurrences of a given list of values in a column using a single SQL query. The operations must be optimised for performance.

Please refer the example given below,

Sample Table name - history

| code_list |
| --- |
| 5lysgj |
| 627czl |
| 1lqnd8 |
| 627czl |
| dtrtvp |
| 627czl |
| esdop9 |
| esdop9 |
| 3by104 |
| 1lqnd8 |

**Expected Output**

Need to get the count of occurrences for these given list of codes 627czl, 1lqnd8, esdop9, aol4m6 in the format given below.

| code | count |
| --- | --- |
| 627czl | 3 |
| esdop9 | 2 |
| 1lqnd8 | 2 |
| aol4m6 | 0 |

Method I tried in show below but the count of each input is shown as a new column using this query,

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when h.code_list = 'esdop9' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_esdop9,
    sum(case when h.code_list = '627czl' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_627czl,
    sum(case when h.code_list = '1lqnd8' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_1lqnd8,
    sum(case when h.code_list = 'aol4m6' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_aol4m6
FROM history h;
```

Note - The number inputs need to be given in the query in 10 also the real table has millions of records.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 4):

If i properly understand you need to get the count of occurrences for the following codes: `627czl`, `1lqnd8`, `esdop9`.

In this case you can try this one:

```
SELECT code_list, count(*) as count_
  FROM history
 WHERE code_list in ('627czl','1lqnd8','esdop9')
 GROUP BY code_list
 ORDER BY count_ DESC;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MSJW6BuA)

If you need to get the count of occurrences for all codes you can run the following query:

```
SELECT code_list, count(*) as count_
  FROM history
 GROUP BY code_list
 ORDER BY count_ DESC;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But what should I do to get the inputs with 0 occurrences in the output as count 0?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use GROUP BY
Something like this

```
SELECT code_list, COUNT(1) as 'total' ROM h GROUP by code_list order by 'total' ;
```

Comment: `FROM` not `ROM`